# Counting the number of LLVM instructions executed dynamically using LLI

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I wanted to count the number of LLVM instruction executed dynamically in any program, using lli 3.4.

I checked [this](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2002-December/000336.html) link, but it's not giving any information related to instruction count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in way in LLVM to do this, AFAIK. However, you have a number of simple options:

1. You can hack the interpreter (which `lli` can run) to count how many instructions it executed.
2. You can instrument the IR before running it by incrementing a counter on entry to each basic block. Then you can run the instrumented IR through either the interpreter or JIT.

Comment: in your second solution: how we will then find out about the workload that each basic block has? That is, to put some weight on each counter, depending on how "heavy" the bb is, in order to conclude whether one execution did more work than another.
Thanks!

Comment: @Paschalis, I think you can first count the number of instructions present in a BB. And then can insert a call to an external function at the end of the BB, which takes this count as an argument. In this manner you'll get the exact count of executed instruction.